# what is the android equivalent to ios swipe view

Tags: android

I am new to android and looking for a control that swipes through images. Is it swipeview or is there something better to put a set of images on that the customer can swipe across?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Here's an [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)